# Can't install Synaptics displaylink-driver on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: displaylink

Can't install the Displaylink driver from Synaptics https://www.synaptics.com/products/displaylink-graphics/downloads/ubuntu

Below has a warning message `dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libc-bin' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed`

followed by the first error at make: `bad exit status: 2`

```
sudo apt install displaylink-driver Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done Reading state information... Done The
following additional packages will be installed:   evdi libdrm-dev
libpciaccess-dev The following NEW packages will be installed:  
displaylink-driver evdi libdrm-dev libpciaccess-dev 0 to upgrade, 4 to
newly install, 0 to remove and 1 not to upgrade. Need to get 0 B/5,452
kB of archives. After this operation, 1,397 kB of additional disk
space will be used. Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y Selecting
previously unselected package libpciaccess-dev:amd64. dpkg: warning:
files list file for package 'libc-bin' missing; assuming package has
no files currently installed (Reading database ... 222433 files and
directories currently installed.) Preparing to unpack
.../libpciaccess-dev_0.16-3_amd64.deb ... Unpacking
libpciaccess-dev:amd64 (0.16-3) ... Selecting previously unselected
package libdrm-dev:amd64. Preparing to unpack
.../libdrm-dev_2.4.113-2~ubuntu0.22.04.1_amd64.deb ... Unpacking
libdrm-dev:amd64 (2.4.113-2~ubuntu0.22.04.1) ... Selecting previously
unselected package evdi. Preparing to unpack
.../evdi_1.13.1-18_amd64.deb ... Unpacking evdi (1.13.1-18) ...
Selecting previously unselected package displaylink-driver. Preparing
to unpack .../displaylink-driver_5.7.0-129_amd64.deb ... Unpacking
displaylink-driver (5.7.0-129) ... Setting up libpciaccess-dev:amd64
(0.16-3) ... Setting up libdrm-dev:amd64 (2.4.113-2~ubuntu0.22.04.1)
... Setting up evdi (1.13.1-18) ... Creating symlink
/var/lib/dkms/evdi/1.13.1/source -> /usr/src/evdi-1.13.1

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel. Skipping...

Building module: cleaning build area... make -j4
KERNELRELEASE=5.15.0-78-generic all
INCLUDEDIR=/lib/modules/5.15.0-78-generic/build/include
KVERSION=5.15.0-78-generic DKMS_BUILD=1...(bad exit status: 2) ERROR:
Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists:
'/var/crash/evdi.0.crash' Error! Bad return status for module build on
kernel: 5.15.0-78-generic (x86_64) Consult
/var/lib/dkms/evdi/1.13.1/build/make.log for more information. dpkg:
error processing package evdi (--configure):  installed evdi package
post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of displaylink-driver:
displaylink-driver depends on evdi (>= 1.13.1); however:   Package
evdi is not configured yet.  displaylink-driver depends on evdi (<<
1.14.0); however:   Package evdi is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package displaylink-driver (--configure): 
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured No apport report written
because the error message indicates its a followup error from a
previous failure.
       Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1) ... Errors were 
       encountered while processing:  evdi  displaylink-driver E: Sub-process
/usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

This install worked ok on another ubuntu machine.  Suspect the issue here is a couple of months ago I did the `sudo ./displaylink-driver-x.x.x.xx.run` install method.  That install didn't work and gave up.

Comment: Anybody know a solution to this issue? Otherwise what to do to find a solution.

Comment: Seeing the same error, with "Package evdi is not configured yet.", using Ubuntu 22.04. It was working until recently.

Comment: Related: see also my answer here: [Full instructions: installing displaylink-driver on Ubuntu 20.04 (also applies to 22.04 or later)](https://askubuntu.com/a/1488249/327339)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure how I got my laptop into this state, but installing `evdi-dkms` allowed the displaylink install to work OK finally, after trying to many things and consistently seeing EVDI related errors.

- `sudo apt install evdi-dkms`
- `sudo apt install displaylink-driver`

This fix was [described on the displaylink forum](https://displaylink.org/forum/showthread.php?t=67852).

Comment: This does *not* work on Ubuntu 20.04. See m Q: [Installing displaylink-driver on Ubuntu 20.04: unmet dependency `evdi`](https://askubuntu.com/q/1487364/327339)

Comment: Solved: [Full instructions: installing displaylink-driver on Ubuntu 20.04 (also applies to 22.04 or later)](https://askubuntu.com/a/1488249/327339)

Comment: No joy with 'sudo apt install evdi-dkms'. Stops at "Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.15.0-86-generic (x86_64)". Associated make.log says "ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid. include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing. Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it."

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with installation myself. After trying everything I finally decided to undo everything by deleting the installed Displaylink driver and evdi (you can find help with that here [How to uninstall DisplayLink Ubuntu software](https://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/683699-how-to-uninstall-displaylink-ubuntu-software) )

I then went to install everything from the beginning by following Synaptics instructions on how to install a standalone installer (you can find the installer here [Ubuntu Driver Download](https://www.synaptics.com/products/displaylink-graphics/downloads/ubuntu))

Just follow the instructions from here: [How to install DisplayLink software on legacy Ubuntu versions](https://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/684649)

After the installation, I needed to add MOK keys in BIOS for secure boot (the installation itself will guide you if you will need to add them) and now everything is working fine.

I hope this helps.